# How to use sql in parametre

Tags: sql, select, search, parameters

```
Declare @record_status varchar(50)

İf @record_status=‘X’
@record_status=‘A’
Else if @record_status Is null
@record_status=‘’’A’’,’’P’’’

Select*from .....where RECORD_STATUS in(@record_status)
```

Else if not searching in the sql somebody help to me

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text. Also tag the dbms you're using, because that code attempt is product specific.

Answer (score 1):

***IF*** you mean what I think you mean, this could do it...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  (@record_status = 'X'   AND table.record_status = 'A')
  OR
  (@record_status IS NULL AND table.record_status IN ('A', 'P'))
```

But your post is very vague ;)